# Mysterious for-loop iteration

Tags: javascript, for-loop, arguments

In the following code, the for-loop starts with i = 1. How come the name property of the merged object is properly set?

```
function merge(root){
  for ( var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++ ){
    for ( var key in arguments[i] ){
      console.log(i); // returns 1 then 2 (not 0)
      root[key] = arguments[i][key];
    }
  }
  return root;
}

var merged = merge({name: "John"}, {city: "Boston"},{age: 13});
console.log( merged.name ); // "John" ?
console.log( merged.city ); // "Boston" - OK 
console.log( merged.age ); // 13 - OK
```

If I set the loop start with `i = 2`, `merged.city` returns `undefined` (as expected), while `merged.name` still returns "John".

```
function merge(root){
  for ( var i = 2; i < arguments.length; i++ ){
    for ( var key in arguments[i] ){
      console.log(i); // returns 2
      root[key] = arguments[i][key];
    }
  }
  return root;
}

var merged = merge({name: "John"}, {city: "Boston"},{age: 13});
console.log( merged.name ); // "John" - ?
console.log( merged.city ); // undefined - OK
console.log( merged.age ); // 13 - OK
```

How is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter `root` refers to the object `{name: "John"}`. This is also `arguments[0]`. That's why we skip it and start at `arguments[1]` — all of the subsequent arguments are merged into it.

Comment: Got it. I thought the parameter `root` referred to an object containing all arguments - that's what it returns if I use `console.log(root)` inside the function.

Comment: @zok: Well, you weren't wrong. It's just that the object in the first argument is both an input (as the first argument) and an output (as the object that all the other arguments get merged into). It's a busy little object.

Answer (score 2):

You probably missed the fact that your method accepts a parameter you then return

```
function merge(root) {
  ...
  return root
```

so that when you feed it with

```
merge( {name: "John"}, ...
```

it will use `{name: "John"}` as `root` and merge other arguments into it.

Comment: This is correct, use `console.log(JSON.stringify(merged))` to inspect your variable.